# Exception thrown: 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

So I keep getting the error

> Exception thrown: 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException'

For my array counter. I'm still learning Visual Basic but I have programming knowledge in other languages, so I'm not sure if I'm just not translating between syntax properly here, or if it's just a logic error I'm not seeing.

The `arrayNumsMultiply()` array is an Integer array declared with 6 values. My counter variable was also declared as an Integer previously in the program.

The following code is meant to count through the 6 numbers, check if they have two integers in them (ex: 47, so 4 and 7), and then add them together. From there, it stores it back into the array and wipes the previous value. I have a `System.Console.WriteLine` in the code to see if the If statement is even being initiated and it's not, but the counter console log is. Any idea on what I may be doing wrong? (The specific line where the error is being thrown is the `If arrayNumsMultiply(counter).ToString.Length = 2 Then`)

```
        For counter = 0 To 5
            If arrayNumsMultiply(counter).ToString.Length = 2 Then
                Dim numOne As String = arrayNumsMultiply(counter).ToString().Substring(1, 1)
                Dim numTwo As String = arrayNumsMultiply(counter).ToString().Substring(2, 1)

                Convert.ToInt32(numOne)
                Convert.ToInt32(numTwo)

                Dim totalNum As Integer
                totalNum = numOne + numTwo

                arrayNumsMultiply(counter) = totalNum

                System.Console.WriteLine("If statement for adding in an integer working")
            End If

            System.Console.WriteLine("Counter working")

        Next counter
```

Comment: `counter` is larger or smaller than than the size of the array.  Use the mouse when it breaks to learn more.  You *say* it has six values so `0 To 5` should work, but VS/VB disagrees and we cant see where you created it.

Comment: If you want to access each element or item in an array or collection then it is generally better to use a `For Each` loop or else use the actual array or collection to specify the upper bound of the loop. i.e. `For Each elem In myArray` or `For i = 0 To myArray.GetUpperBound(0)`.

Comment: By the way, if you want to get a single character from a `String`, don't use `Substring`.  You can just index the `String` like an array to get the `Char` at that index.

Comment: @Plutonix `Dim arrayNumsMultiply(6) As Integer` is how it's declared, is that right?

@jmcilhinney I did that and it doesn't change the error happening since the error is on the If statement's line. The for statement itself is executing, just not the If statement.

Answer (score 0):

If the length of you string is 2, the the first character is at position 0 and the second character is at position 1. Like most things in .net this is zero based. So the correct code for these lines is...

```
Dim numOne As String = arrayNumsMultiply(counter).ToString().Substring(0, 1)
Dim numTwo As String = arrayNumsMultiply(counter).ToString().Substring(1, 1)
```